# HTML Mail module not calling template

Tags: 7, emails

I have `htmlmail--htmlmail.tpl.php` in the root of my theme directory (matching the path outlined in the bottom of the test email which tells me I got *some* things right)

Set Mail system to use HTML Email, but when I send a test email from the HTML Mail plugin page, it ignores the template file (originally had it just named `htmlmail.tpl.php`  but I changed it based on what it said at the bottom of the test email.

In the template I just added `<p>TESTING</p>` above the $body variable.

But the test email ignores all of that.

Not sure what else to check or if I'm missing a setup step, I have my template file, set the theme and not worrying about post-filtering (as outlined on the [module page](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail)

The mentioned page does list `Autoload 6.x-2.1 (New for 6.x-2.28)` under requirements, but this seems to only be for Drupal 6 so I did not worry about it and presume that I don't need to.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: And just to be sure: configured in the settings which theme should be used for html emails? With Mime Mail module I saw reports that it only picked the template file up when you put it in your administrative theme.

Comment: it was the stupid cache.. I realized this before posting this.. and then forgot. argh. but thanks!